# Forms login to remote domain using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

The client was to have a normal form to login to the remote domain's windows authentication. I don't think it is possible, but anyone know a way?

Answer (score 0):

Setup your active directory membership provider to point to the remote domain. Give this configuration a try:

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in Multiple Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx)

If you can't get that to work (I believe this is possible though) you could just write your own code to authentication against that domain and create your own Forms Authentication ticket - either way it is possible.